# Angular template libraries

Tags: angular

So in WPF I can create a XAML template library and reference that thru out my code.
Is there a similar way to do that in Angular?  Create an HTML file that has the common templates that I would like to use, and reference those templates in the components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Templates have to be processed by the angular compiler, so there's no good way to do what you're asking unless the HTML is included in some other component of your app (or unless you use some more advanced 'hacks' that will compile that HTML file w/ the angular compiler on-the-fly... or just inject the HTML directly but that's pretty unsafe).

You could make a component called 'Template Library' or whatever, and in that component's template you could include a bunch of ng-template tags that each define each separate template you'd like to reference later in your code. You can get the TemplateRef's of each of these ng-template elements and then use those wherever in your app.

I've done something similar in one of my apps, I wrote a directive that I attach to ng-template elements that automatically gets the TemplateRef of the element, and sends it to a service that stores all the different TemplateRefs. Then elsewhere in my app, I can just use that service to access all of my available templates and inject them wherever I need them. It requires a bit more prep-work than simply referencing an external HTML file, but it gets the job done. You just have to make sure you include the 'TemplateLibrary' component somewhere in your app so the compiler will process those template tags (even though it won't display them until you explicitly inject them elsewhere).